# incrementing the primary key by default,as the records are entered in the databases

Tags: java, jdbc

i was doing a java program,as i was creating my second or third simple program of jdbc,i was entering the information about students in a table,in which there were four fields, the name,city & the roll no of the student which were added manually by the user through the java program(code),but i want that the fourth field id,(which is primary key,hence must be unique)must be generated automatically during the addition of the complete record,& it must be the value one more then the previous id's value present in the table......How could i do this??
i am not too good at sql queries..:)

Answer (score 2):

which IDE are you using????

```
 CREATE TABLE "student"
        (
        "stud_id" INT not null primary key
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),   
        "NAME" VARCHAR(50),     
        "CITY" VARCHAR(50),
        "ROLL NO." INTEGER
        );
```

Comment: @RMT:AS,a am not good at sql queries,hence i was unable to construct such a query for my self,so that i can pass that string to my java code,in the method executeUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

It should be done via server (sql) side, try to read about auto increment for instance [MySQL auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

And Yes, you have not set up auto increment from Java Side, for example if you have student table with some fields  like id (auto_increment), name and age you should set just name and age from java side, id will be added from SQL side.

Comment: can you explain how to do it?

Comment: If you read the link that Sergii has provided with you, the first example is similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @RMT:AS,a am not good at sql queries,hence i was unable to exceute such a query for my self,so that i can pass that string to my java code,in the method executeUpdate()